# Create a kubernetes namespace using config instead of API

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl

The only way to create a new namespace according to [documentation](https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/deploy-master.html) here is to make an API request

```
curl -v -X POST -d'{"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Namespace","metadata":{"name":"kube-system"}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/namespaces"
```

Is there any way to do the same using config or cloud-config?

Comment: FWIW, there's also `kubectl create namespace`; I suppose though you ruled that out as an option already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Timo mentioned, you can use `kubectl create namespace NAME` to create a namespace using the command line client. You can also put the following into a yaml file and use `kubectl create -f namespace.yaml` to create a namespace:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: kube-system
```

Comment: I use coreos with cloud-config for deploy and I don't want to use kubectl at all. I want to place it somewhere in a filesystem (I'll use write-file in cloud-config in that case) or in cloud-config.

Is there any place where I can place this yaml file on a filesystem?

Comment: If you run the [Kubernetes add-on manager](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/addon-manager) then you can stick the file into `/etc/kubernetes/addons` and it will be automatically applied to your cluster.